# DATETIME to real time in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting the time from a Wordpress post (the field being post_date_gmt stored in DATETIME), how can I convert that information (e.g 2011-03-23 20:28:26) to an actual, maleable date in PHP? (like Thursday, March 23rd, 2011)

Comment: `2011-03-23 20:28:26` is an *actual* date, just not in the *format* you want... :P

Comment: I agree! :P use `date(formatString, yourDate)` or `gmdate(formatString, yourDate)` format string example: `'D, d M Y H:i:s T'`

Comment: @deceze Haha! my bad, my bad. You're right, sir. date(formatString, myDate) is what I'm using and with some tweaking, worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo date('r', strtotime($datetime));

echo date('r', strtotime('2011-03-23 20:28:26'));

echo date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime('2011-03-23 20:28:26'));
```

See [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://ca.php.net/strtotime) or the [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class.

```
// Using strtotime
$date = strtotime($row['post_date_gmt']);

// Using the DateTime class
$date = new DateTime($row['post_date_gmt']);
```

Because the date is in GMT and you're server most likely isn't, it may be wise to specify the time zone as well. Here's an example using [`DateTimeZone`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php).

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$date = new DateTime($row['post_date_gmt'], $timezone);
```

Comment: This is good advice, specially the inclusion of the DateTime class - nice to have a few other alternatives that work equally great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
date(formatString, yourDate)
```

or

```
gmdate(formatString, yourDate)
```

format string example: 'D, d M Y H:i:s T'